# Command \widering already defined

Tags: errors, packages

I keep getting this error whenever I start an article with the basic set of packages:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,yhmath,mathrsfs,fancyhdr,enumerate,tkz-euclide,tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{framed,tikz,tkz-tab,tkz-linknodes,pgfplots,currfile,enumerate}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,calc,intersections,angles,patterns,snakes}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=1.5cm] {geometry}
\usepackage[hidelinks,unicode,pdfencoding=unicode, psdextra]{hyperref}
\usepackage[book]{ex_test}
%CÁC GÓI, LỆNH VIẾT TẮT CẦN THÊM
%CẤU TRÚC TỰ LUẬN
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package `fouriernc` tries to define `\widering` but it is already defined by `yhmath`.  You could either get rid of one of the two packages, or put

```
\let\widering\relax
```

before `\usepackage{fouriernc}`.